# Python format hex number

Tags: python, tcp, hex

I need to send a string via tcp. One of the first sections of the string is the length of the command variable

```
Example:
command = STATUS?UPDATE
```

I need to send the following string below

```
sendCommand = '\x00\x00\x00'+STRINGLENGTH+'\x02'+command+'\x0D\x0A'
```

My string length is 11 so I need STRINGLENGTH to be the hex equivalent of 11, which is **0xB**, except that I need it to output as **\x0B**

Padding it with the leading 0 is easy, but I cannot get it to output as **\x** instead of **0x**, and if I do a string replace it is treated as text and not as hex, so it doesn't work.

My final hex string should be:

```
\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x02\x53\x54\x41\x54\x55\x53\x3f\x55\x53\x45\x52\x0D\x0A
```

I am instead getting:

```
\x00\x00\x000x0B\x02\x53\x54\x41\x54\x55\x53\x3f\x55\x53\x45\x52\x0D\x0A
```

Any ideas on how to format it correctly?

Comment: You almost certainly should be working with `bytes`... no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is a bit of a round-about fashion, but use a `bytes` object:

```
>>> STRINGLENGTH = bytes([11]).decode()
>>> endCommand = '\x00\x00\x00'+STRINGLENGTH+'\x02'
>>> endCommand
'\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x02'
```

Almost certainly, you are going to want to change your `str` object back to a `bytes` object, but the above should get you going.

I suspect what you were doing was using the `hex` function:

```
>>> STRINGLENGTH = hex(11)
>>> endCommand = '\x00\x00\x00'+STRINGLENGTH+'\x02'
>>> endCommand
'\x00\x00\x000xb\x02'
```

The fundamental thing you need to understand is that you aren't working with "hex", you are working with *bytes*. Hex is just how bytes are traditionally represented. The `hex` helper function returns a hexadecimal representation, *as a string* of an integer. But that isn't what you want. You want the *byte corresponding to the value 11*.

Note, for the ascii-range, `chr(i)` might works as well, so

```
>>> STRINGLENGTH = chr(11)
>>> endCommand = '\x00\x00\x00'+STRINGLENGTH+'\x02'
>>> endCommand
'\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x02'
```

But be careful, say you wanted the number 129, you have to care about the encoding...

```
>>> chr(129)
'\x81'
```

But in bytes, in UTF-8, that's actually represented by two different bytes

```
>>> chr(129).encode()
b'\xc2\x81'
>>> list(chr(129).encode())
[194, 129]
```

Which of course, depends on the encoding:

```
>>> chr(129).encode('latin')
b'\x81'
>>> list(chr(129).encode('latin'))
[129]
>>>
```

For that reason, I think it is safer to stick with the slightly wordier:

```
>>> bytes([129])
b'\x81'
```

Comment: Yes I am working with bytes. The piece of equipment will not be available to me again until late tomorrow so I will try this then.

I tried something very similar, but left out the brackets around the 11, which did not work (hopefully just because of the missing brackets).

I also tried hex() and format(STRINGLENGTH, 'x') both produced the same issue.

Comment: `bytes(11)` initializes bytes object of *length* 11, initialized with null bytes. see `help(bytes)` for the different forms for the constructor

Comment: The ascii chr() approach worked for me. I am strictly working in ascii, with no user input. So my inputs are fairly controlled (a number, and a pre-defined command). Thank you so much for the help.